# How do I extract this particular element from this webpage using axios, reactjs, and cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios, cheerio

I'm trying to extract live commodity prices from the CME group via web scraping using axios and cheerio. I'm having trouble finding the correct path for cheerio to get each element in the table I'm scraping. I'm trying right now to just get the Month JLY20 from the span tag for each row.

Link to the actual webpage: https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/metals/base/copper_quotes_settlements_futures.html

Heres what I have right now:

Server.js

```
  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/metals/base/copper_quotes_settlements_futures.html`)
      .then(response => {
        if(response.status === 200)
          {
            const html = response.data;
            const $ = cheerio.load(html);
            let data = [];
            $('table.cmeTable').each((i, elem) => {
                console.log($(elem).find('span.noWrap').text())
                data.push({
                  Month: $(elem).find('th.cmeFixedColumn').text()
                  // title: $(elem).find('h2.entry-title').text(),
                  // excerpt: $(elem).find('p.hide_xxs').text().trim(),
                  // link: $(elem).find('h2.entry-title a').attr('href')
                })

            });
            console.log(data);
            // fs.writeFile('devtoList.json',
            // JSON.stringify(devtoListTrimmed, null, 4),
            // (err)=> console.log('File successfully written!'))
          }
        }, (error) => console.log('err') );
  }
```

Here's the target reference's source code:

```
<div class="cmeTableBlockWrapper cmeContentSection cmeContentGroup" style=""><div class="cmeTableResponsiveScrollableWrapper">
<table id="settlementsFuturesProductTable" class="cmeTable" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" summary="Settlements Table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="invisibleElement cmeFixedColumn" style="height: 33px; width: 120px; min-width: 120px;">Month</th>
            <th scope="col">Open</th>
            <th scope="col">High</th>
            <th scope="col">Low</th>
            <th scope="col">Last</th>
            <th scope="col">Change</th>
            <th scope="col">Settle</th>
            <th scope="col">Estimated Volume</th>
            <th scope="col">Prior Day Open Interest</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="invisibleElement cmeFixedColumn" style="height: 41px; width: 120px;"><span class="noWrap">JLY 20</span></th>
            <td>2.8990</td>
            <td>2.9210</td>
            <td>2.8945</td>
            <td>2.9155</td>
            <td><span>-.0260</span></td>
            <td>2.9160</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">818</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">3,140</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="invisibleElement cmeFixedColumn" style="height: 41px; width: 120px;"><span class="noWrap">AUG 20</span></th>
            <td>2.9105</td>
            <td>2.9330</td>
            <td>2.8980</td>
            <td>2.9270</td>
            <td><span>-.0245</span></td>
            <td>2.9250</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">191</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">2,994</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="invisibleElement cmeFixedColumn" style="height: 41px; width: 120px;"><span class="noWrap">SEP 20</span></th>
            <td>2.9160</td>
            <td>2.9460</td>
            <td>2.8980</td>
            <td>2.9300</td>
            <td><span>-.0225</span></td>
            <td>2.9325</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">80,068</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">115,684</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="invisibleElement cmeFixedColumn" style="height: 41px; width: 120px;"><span class="noWrap">OCT 20</span></th>
            <td>2.9350</td>
            <td>2.9400</td>
            <td>2.9280</td>
            <td>2.9400</td>
            <td><span>-.0220</span></td>
            <td>2.9405</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">10</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">2,012</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="invisibleElement cmeFixedColumn" style="height: 41px; width: 120px;"><span class="noWrap">NOV 20</span></th>
            <td>2.9375</td>
            <td>2.9380</td>
            <td>2.9330</td>
            <td>2.9330</td>
            <td><span>-.0215</span></td>
            <td>2.9470</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">10</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">2,123</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="invisibleElement cmeFixedColumn" style="height: 41px; width: 120px;"><span class="noWrap">DEC 20</span></th>
            <td>2.9340</td>
            <td>2.9630</td>
            <td>2.9150</td>
            <td>2.9480B</td>
            <td><span>-.0205</span></td>
            <td>2.9505</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">12,155</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">52,370</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="invisibleElement cmeFixedColumn" style="height: 41px; width: 120px;"><span class="noWrap">JAN 21</span></th>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>2.9465A</td>
            <td>2.9465A</td>
            <td><span>-.0195</span></td>
            <td>2.9560</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">4</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">592</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="invisibleElement cmeFixedColumn" style="height: 41px; width: 120px;"><span class="noWrap">FEB 21</span></th>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>2.9525A</td>
            <td>2.9525A</td>
            <td><span>-.0195</span></td>
            <td>2.9590</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">0</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">361</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="invisibleElement cmeFixedColumn" style="height: 41px; width: 120px;"><span class="noWrap">MAR 21</span></th>
            <td>2.9535</td>
            <td>2.9720</td>
            <td>2.9300</td>
            <td>2.9590</td>
            <td><span>-.0185</span></td>
            <td>2.9615</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">8,055</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">31,345</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="invisibleElement cmeFixedColumn" style="height: 41px; width: 120px;"><span class="noWrap">APR 21</span></th>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>2.9575A</td>
            <td>2.9575A</td>
            <td><span>-.0175</span></td>
            <td>2.9650</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">0</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">181</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="invisibleElement cmeFixedColumn" style="height: 41px; width: 120px;"><span class="noWrap">MAY 21</span></th>
            <td>2.9665</td>
            <td>2.9720</td>
            <td>2.9480</td>
            <td>2.9655B</td>
            <td><span>-.0165</span></td>
            <td>2.9655</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">1,619</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">6,208</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="invisibleElement cmeFixedColumn" style="height: 41px; width: 120px;"><span class="noWrap">JUN 21</span></th>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>2.9610A</td>
            <td>2.9610A</td>
            <td><span>-.0155</span></td>
            <td>2.9685</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">0</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">160</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="invisibleElement cmeFixedColumn" style="height: 41px; width: 120px;"><span class="noWrap">JLY 21</span></th>
            <td>2.9585</td>
            <td>2.9755B</td>
            <td>2.9540</td>
            <td>2.9670B</td>
            <td><span>-.0155</span></td>
            <td>2.9690</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">471</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">934</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="invisibleElement cmeFixedColumn" style="height: 41px; width: 120px;"><span class="noWrap">AUG 21</span></th>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>2.9640A</td>
            <td>2.9640A</td>
            <td><span>-.0160</span></td>
            <td>2.9715</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">0</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">114</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="invisibleElement cmeFixedColumn" style="height: 41px; width: 120px;"><span class="noWrap">SEP 21</span></th>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>2.9635A</td>
            <td>2.9635A</td>
            <td><span>-.0155</span></td>
            <td>2.9720</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">4</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">437</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="invisibleElement cmeFixedColumn" style="height: 41px; width: 120px;"><span class="noWrap">OCT 21</span></th>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>2.9685A</td>
            <td>2.9685A</td>
            <td><span>-.0160</span></td>
            <td>2.9755</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">0</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">79</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="invisibleElement cmeFixedColumn" style="height: 41px; width: 120px;"><span class="noWrap">NOV 21</span></th>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>2.9720A</td>
            <td>2.9720A</td>
            <td><span>-.0160</span></td>
            <td>2.9760</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">0</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">33</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="invisibleElement cmeFixedColumn" style="height: 41px; width: 120px;"><span class="noWrap">DEC 21</span></th>
            <td>2.9795</td>
            <td>2.9795</td>
            <td>2.9520A</td>
            <td>2.9680</td>
            <td><span>-.0155</span></td>
            <td>2.9765</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">65</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">1,065</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="invisibleElement cmeFixedColumn" style="height: 41px; width: 120px;"><span class="noWrap">JAN 22</span></th>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td><span>-.0155</span></td>
            <td>2.9795</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">0</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="invisibleElement cmeFixedColumn" style="height: 41px; width: 120px;"><span class="noWrap">FEB 22</span></th>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td><span>-.0145</span></td>
            <td>2.9820</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">0</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="invisibleElement cmeFixedColumn" style="height: 41px; width: 120px;"><span class="noWrap">MAR 22</span></th>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td><span>-.0135</span></td>
            <td>2.9830</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">0</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">136</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="invisibleElement cmeFixedColumn" style="height: 41px; width: 120px;"><span class="noWrap">APR 22</span></th>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td><span>-.0155</span></td>
            <td>2.9910</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">0</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="invisibleElement cmeFixedColumn" style="height: 41px; width: 120px;"><span class="noWrap">MAY 22</span></th>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td><span>-.0145</span></td>
            <td>2.9905</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">0</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="invisibleElement cmeFixedColumn" style="height: 41px; width: 120px;"><span class="noWrap">JUN 22</span></th>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td><span>-.0145</span></td>
            <td>2.9930</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">0</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="invisibleElement cmeFixedColumn" style="height: 41px; width: 120px;"><span class="noWrap">JLY 22</span></th>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td><span>-.0145</span></td>
            <td>2.9935</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">0</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">20</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="invisibleElement cmeFixedColumn" style="height: 41px; width: 120px;"><span class="noWrap">SEP 22</span></th>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td><span>-.0145</span></td>
            <td>2.9995</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">0</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="invisibleElement cmeFixedColumn" style="height: 41px; width: 120px;"><span class="noWrap">DEC 22</span></th>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td><span>-.0145</span></td>
            <td>3.0030</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">0</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">25</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="invisibleElement cmeFixedColumn" style="height: 41px; width: 120px;"><span class="noWrap">MAR 23</span></th>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td><span>-.0145</span></td>
            <td>3.0070</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">0</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="invisibleElement cmeFixedColumn" style="height: 41px; width: 120px;"><span class="noWrap">MAY 23</span></th>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td><span>-.0145</span></td>
            <td>3.0095</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">0</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="invisibleElement cmeFixedColumn" style="height: 41px; width: 120px;"><span class="noWrap">JLY 23</span></th>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td><span>-.0145</span></td>
            <td>3.0125</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">0</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="invisibleElement cmeFixedColumn" style="height: 41px; width: 120px;"><span class="noWrap">SEP 23</span></th>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td><span>-.0145</span></td>
            <td>3.0150</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">0</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="invisibleElement cmeFixedColumn" style="height: 41px; width: 120px;"><span class="noWrap">DEC 23</span></th>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td><span>-.0145</span></td>
            <td>3.0440</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">0</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="invisibleElement cmeFixedColumn" style="height: 41px; width: 120px;"><span class="noWrap">MAR 24</span></th>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td><span>-.0145</span></td>
            <td>3.0445</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">0</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="invisibleElement cmeFixedColumn" style="height: 41px; width: 120px;"><span class="noWrap">MAY 24</span></th>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td><span>-.0145</span></td>
            <td>3.0450</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">0</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="invisibleElement cmeFixedColumn" style="height: 41px; width: 120px;"><span class="noWrap">JLY 24</span></th>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td><span>-.0145</span></td>
            <td>3.0455</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">0</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="invisibleElement cmeFixedColumn" style="height: 41px; width: 120px;"><span class="noWrap">SEP 24</span></th>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td><span>-.0145</span></td>
            <td>3.0460</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">0</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="invisibleElement cmeFixedColumn" style="height: 41px; width: 120px;"><span class="noWrap">DEC 24</span></th>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td><span>-.0145</span></td>
            <td>3.0465</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">0</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="invisibleElement cmeFixedColumn" style="height: 41px; width: 120px;"><span class="noWrap">MAR 25</span></th>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td><span>-.0145</span></td>
            <td>3.0470</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">0</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="invisibleElement cmeFixedColumn" style="height: 41px; width: 120px;"><span class="noWrap">MAY 25</span></th>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td>-</td>
            <td><span>-.0145</span></td>
            <td>3.0475</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">0</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th scope="row" class="invisibleElement cmeFixedColumn" style="height: 41px; width: 120px;"><span class="noWrap">Total</span></th>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><span></span></td>
            <td></td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">103,470</td>
            <td class="cmeTableRight">220,022</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried copying the xpath from developer tools?

Comment: but would that go in the $(' ')? or in the find portion?

Comment: Please post the HTML as code for us to be able to test it. Thanks

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira updated.

Answer (score 1):

From reviewing the site you linked: the reason you are not able to select the content is because the data table is loaded asynchronously; this means your script executes before the HTML has renderered.

If you open the devtools for the [site you linked](https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/metals/base/copper_quotes_settlements_futures.html), you can see there is an asynchronous call to [this endpoint](https://www.cmegroup.com/CmeWS/mvc/Settlements/Futures/Settlements/438/FUT?tradeDate=07/14/2020&strategy=DEFAULT&pageSize=500&_=1594759356545).

A better strategy would be to collect the data from the URL I linked to above.

Edit: on further examination of the source code, you can get the data you need to construct the async URL from `window.cmeComponents`

Comment: so would that be $('window.cmeComponents')... ?

Comment: With the strategy I oulined above, you would only need to call the endpoint I linked above, cast it to JSON and loop through the array using plain JS.

Comment: would it be possible to apply it to this website as well: https://www.investing.com/commodities/real-time-futures ?

Comment: Not from that specific site, as the HTML table is hard coded. In the case of that particular website, you can query the DOM elements and loop through them. For the original website you linked, you would be better off using the direct async call to their internal API.

Comment: for the investing.com site, would the appropriate cheerio call be $('table#cross_rates_1 ').each((i,element) => ...)

Comment: For the site you linked to in your comment, it would be `$("#cross_rate_1")`. The best way to test this would be in the dev tools. Open the link and enter `document.querySelector("#cross_rate_1")` into the JavaScript console. `document.querySelector` and `document.querySelectorAll` map well to Cheerio selectors.

Comment: but then how do I get the tbody element that has the actual element row values

Comment: Open the dev tools and execute this: `[...document.querySelectorAll("#cross_rate_1 td")].forEach(td => console.log(td.innerText));`. It will return the value of all `td`s inside the `#cross_rate_1` table.

Comment: but if I'm using reactjs, axios, and cheerios, I can't use the document.querySelector function, right?